# JOINS in the query end up displaying too many rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Below is my query:

```
 $query = "
          SELECT DISTINCT gr.SessionId, t.TeacherUsername, t.TeacherForename,
                          t.TeacherSurname, cm.ModuleId, m.ModuleName, 
                          cm.CourseId, c.CourseName, st.Year, st.StudentUsername, 
                          st.StudentForename, st.StudentSurname, gr.Mark, gr.Grade
          FROM Teacher t
          INNER JOIN Session s ON t.TeacherId = s.TeacherId
          JOIN Grade_Report gr ON s.SessionId = gr.SessionId
          JOIN Student st ON gr.StudentId = st.StudentId
          JOIN Course c ON st.CourseId = c.CourseId
          JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
          JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
          WHERE
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."' = '' OR gr.SessionId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."')
          ORDER BY $orderfield ASC
          ";
```

You don't need to worry about the WHERE clause and ORDER BY clause. My problem is that the query result shows 26 rows when it should show 13 rows.

I know the reason for this and it is because the Course_Module table is a cross reference table between Course table and Module table and is needed so that it is able to link Course table and Module table together.

But Course Table uses CourseId to JOIN another table and so does Course_Module Table. So CourseId is used twice in the JOINS section and because of this it is duplicating rows again. So there should be 13 rows but because each row is duplicate it shows 26.

I tried     GROUP BY cm.CourseId but it ends up displaying 2 rows which are two different CourseId which is not what I want at all.

So what my question is that is there are way I can use the Course_Module table to JOIN tables but ignore it when it comes to displaying results?

If query was this:

```
 $query = "
          SELECT DISTINCT gr.SessionId, t.TeacherUsername, t.TeacherForename,
                          t.TeacherSurname, cm.ModuleId, m.ModuleName, 
                          cm.CourseId, c.CourseName, st.Year, st.StudentUsername, 
                          st.StudentForename, st.StudentSurname, gr.Mark, gr.Grade
          FROM Teacher t
          INNER JOIN Session s ON t.TeacherId = s.TeacherId
          JOIN Grade_Report gr ON s.SessionId = gr.SessionId
          JOIN Student st ON gr.StudentId = st.StudentId
          JOIN Course c ON st.CourseId = c.CourseId;
```

This query shows 13 rows but it means there is no link to Module Table so don't know name of Modules taken for each grade reort.

Below is example of result I am getting at moment:

```
Student    Session         Module          Course         Grade
S1         AAA             CHT2520         ICT            A
S1         AAA             CHT2520         ICT            A
S2         AAA             CHT2520         ICT            B
S2         AAA             CHT2520         ICT            B
S3         AAB             CHT2220         BIT            D
S3         AAB             CHT2220         BIT            D
S4         AAC             CHI2250         COMP           A
S4         AAC             CHI2250         COMP           A
```

It should be:

Below is result I am getting at moment:

```
Student    Session         Module          Course         Grade
S1         AAA             CHT2520         ICT            A
S2         AAA             CHT2520         ICT            B
S3         AAB             CHT2220         BIT            D
S4         AAC             CHI2250         COMP           A
```

Thank You

Comment: Dude, you should really consider the use of VIEWS if you need this kind of join.

Comment: Views should be avoided on MySQL.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is coming from the Course_Module table? From what you describe "...it ends up displaying 2 rows which are two different CourseId..." it seems to suggest that at the point that join is made you already have additional data. What are you expecting to have 13 of? If you comment out the Course and Course_Module joins and columns do you drop down to your expected 13 rows?

Comment: Yes if I have no Course_Module Table and no Module Table, I get 13 rows but if I include them I get 26 rows. The 13 rows are each duplicated hence I get 26 rows.

Comment: I don't understand your situation.  Can you simplify your query and show sample data?  From what you are saying you should still see the problem with just 3 tables?

Comment: If there is no Course_Module table in the JOIN, then the query will work as it will show 13 rows which is correct as there are only 13 grade reports. But it means I can't link to Module table so you won't know what the name of the Modules are. That is why I need Course_Module table to JOIN with Module table. But when I include this each row duplicates itself by +1. You look at my other Joins they all use different fields to JOIN with each other except for Course and course_Module which both require CourseId and that is why I am getting duplicates. I'm sure on that but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Simple example is better.  Also not clear with is DISTINCT not solving your problem?  You really should come up with a simple example including data, you are not clear.

Comment: So are you saying MySQL'd DISTINCT Doesn't work?

Comment: Yes the DISTINCT clause is not working, the first sample data you see of the results shown is what the query is outputting at moment but I want the second sample data to be outputted. Why is it not letting me do this

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that DISTINCT doesn't work at all.  Try creating 3 simple tables with 2-3 rows of data in each and reproduce your problem with this, then post full details (data in each table + queries).

Comment: Dude, It is 4:30 in the morning in the UK and I am really tired,  I really appreciate your help but I am too tired to recreate tables. Can I just trust you and I be able to send you my full code to you so you can have a proper look?

Comment: @MK - look as his code. He has 14 columns selected. His results only show 5. Somewhere in the 9 missing rows there will be a difference to make each record unique.

Comment: @Joel yeah, you are 100% right.

Comment: Yeah but that was just something I made up Joel. That isn't the actual result it is showing, that was giving you an indication on the duplication I have been getting. That sample data was made up. I know If I don't include Couse_Module in JOIN and thus there is no Module table in JOIN, I will get 13 rows but you won't know what Module each student is taking becuase that information comes from the Module table.

Comment: I'm going a sleep now, Im too tired, if you have  any ideas on how to fix the roblem then please share it and I will look at when I wake up, other than that thank you for your help :)

Comment: He just told you.  Your "duplicate" rows are not really duplicates, there is at least one column different between them.  Now stop arguing,take a nap, look at your data carefully and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your select clause asks for 14 columns. The results you showed only had 5. If you limit your select clause to those 5 columns, you'll get the 13 rows that you want.

To include all 14 columns, look at the other columns in the results. Realize that right now, you don't have 26 rows in your result set so much as you have 13 *pairs* of rows.  Look carefully at each pair, and somewhere you'll find a column that's different — something that distinguishes one record in a matched pair from the other.  Add a condition to the join on the table that hosts this column to prevent one of the values from making it to your results, and you'll get the right number of rows. This may require a [derived table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/DerivedTables/61388/) or [correlated sub-query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) in the join condition to limit the join to only the first match (for some definition of "first" determined by the sub query).

Comment: @MK it looks at every column in your select list. Your query has 14 columns in the select list, but your sample data only shows us 5 columns. DISTINCT will make sure each record in your result set is unique, but it will look at all 14 columns in your select list to do so. Somewhere in the 9 un-shown columns, each pair of rows will have a value that is different.

Comment: I understand now you are saying select fields one by run and run the query and keep doing it until I find the field that is causing the duplicate. I understand now, Thank you I will get onto that when I wake up, Cheers :)

Comment: I don't think you quite get it yet. Selecting one column at a time with distinct is likely to not return as many rows as you want, and thus make finding the offending column difficult. Better just carefully read over the results of one entire matched pair and find which column is different. Make sure you're not using Management studio for this, as it has a tendency to truncate long results.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a big expert but why are you using two different joins in your case? Stick to INNER JOIN throughout the query and it might fix the issue.

Comment: That is how you suppose to do it, you don't need to keep writing INNER JOIN, you can write INNER JOIN once then continue with JOIN

Comment: I don't understand what the OP is actually trying to do, but the various joins have different meaning. Use the right sequence of joins for the job.

Comment: Is there a way 2 fieids can join with one field aka: FROM Teacher t, Module m INNER JOIN Session s ON t.TeacherId = s.TeacherId AND m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId ?

Comment: 2 different joins?  JOIN and INNER JOIN should be the same.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, I tried with all INNER JOINS and same result, the way I have done it is the way I have been taught